# Automatic distribution of data onto groupplots with violinplots

Tags: loops, external-files, groupplots

I am rather new to latex and pgfplots, but have to plot a rather complicated plot. I need a set of (120+) violinplots and it would be great if I could provide the data from a file (in any format, which may help), maybe provide a number_of_plots_per_group=20, and have the plots be generated in a for loop. The end result should look something like:
[image]

Some sample data to play with may look like:

```
A 1.0 2.0 3.0 0.5
B 0.3 1.2 2.4
C 1.0 2.0 3.0 0.5 0.3 1.2 2.4
```

Any part of the puzzle would help me. For one, using a simpler example, I cannot figure out how to distribute the data from one data file automatically across multiple plots without splitting the files. In the following example, how would one distribute the entries automatically?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{tikzviolinplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group name=myplot,
            group size= 1 by 2,
            vertical sep=2cm, % Adjust vertical spacing between plots
        },
        ybar,
        height=5cm,
        width=\textwidth,
        xtick=data, % Use the data points as x ticks
        % xticklabels from table={\mydata}{Category}, % Use the 'Category' column for x tick labels
        xticklabel style={rotate=45, anchor=east}, % Rotate the x tick labels for better visibility
        ]

    \pgfplotstableread[]{%
Category         Value
R115             0.0250522
R116             0.010669
R12              0.0168477
R1224YDZ         0.0453421
R123             0.0131629
R1233ZDE         0.0326974
    }\mydata

        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x in {1,2} {
            \nextgroupplot[title=type\x, ylabel={}]
            \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=Value]{\mydata};
        };

    \end{groupplot} ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For the following data in the file:

```
Category         Value
R115             0.0250522
R116             0.010669
R12              0.0168477
R1224YDZ         0.0453421
R123             0.0131629
R1233ZDE         0.0326974
```

## Edit

I added several line so that it can now be compiled, as rightfully requested by @MS-SPO. Also, in the meantime, I got a loop to work -> one step closer :)

Comment: Welcome. // May I ask you a favor? If so, please copy your posted code into a new file and compile it. Keep adding missing lines, until it does. Once it still shows your problem, please update the code in your question. Thank you

Comment: You are right, thank you @MS-SPO

Comment: Interesting package https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzviolinplots . Why don't you use its functionality, i.e. why don't you use a single command having *viol* in its name?